# Mount directory for non-admin users on a dual boot setup

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, mount, ntfs, fstab

I have a dual boot PC (Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome, windows Vista) and admin uses all drives, including the C drive of windows.

I would like to allow standard-privileged users to be able to read (not write, only access a document) a single subdirectory named A from the drive C.

So, in `/etc/fstab` file, `/media/123.../A` (`C:\A` in windows) should be linked to the users' documents/A directory (`/home/user/Documents/A`), only for standard users (not admins).

This should include the subdirectories of A too and all files. 
Is there a way to do it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set permissions for a Windows partition, but you can't set permissions to individual files/folders under the partition; at the time of mounting, you set the permissions to the **whole** drive.

In your question, you have not mentioned whether the standard-privileged users need to have "read-only access to the subdirectory `A` **and write access to the rest of the Windows partition**", or "read-only access to subdirectory `A` **and no access to the rest of the partition**". Unfortunately though, both of these scenarios cannot be exactly accomplished, due to the opening sentence of this answer.

If you want to give a user read-only access to a specific folder under the Windows partition, that user will have read-only access to the whole partition. If this is okay with you, then here's an explanation on how to do this:

1. First, create a group for the users that will have read-only access. For the sake of this example, we'll use `WindowsRO`. So, the command to create the group is:

   ```
   sudo groupadd WindowsRO
   ```
2. Second, we'll add the users (that we want to give read-only access to) to the group. Assuming that a user is called `notadmin`, this is the command:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G WindowsRO notadmin
   ```

   Repeat this command for all the required users.
3. Now, we need to get the GID (group ID) of the group, because we'll use it when mounting the drive. To do that, execute the following:

   ```
   grep WindowsRO /etc/group | cut -d: -f3
   ```

   Note down the number that's outputted, because we'll need that in step 5. For this example, I'll assume the output is `1003`.
4. Now, we need to get the UID (user ID) of the admin account, because we'll use it when mounting the drive. This example will assume that the admin account is `bob`. To do that, execute the following:

   ```
   grep bob /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f3
   ```

   Note down the number that's outputted, because we'll need that in step 5. For this example, I'll assume the output is `1000`.
5. We will now edit the `/etc/fstab` file. I'll assume that the Windows partition in question is `/dev/sda2`, that you're mounting it on `/media/123`, and that it's an `ntfs` partition. This is the line that you should have:

   ```
   /dev/sda2    /media/123    ntfs    rw,gid=1003,uid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=037,#AnyOtherOptions#
   ```

   - `gid=1003` is the number we got from step 3 (the GID of the group).
   - `uid=1000` is the number we got from step 4 (the UID of the admin account).
   - `dmask=027` sets the permissions on folders to be: `-rwxr-x---`, which means that the owner (the admin account) will have full access (`rwx`), and the group will only have read access (`r-x`), and anyone else will not have access at all (`---`).
   - `fmask=037` sets the permissions on files to be: `-rwxr-----`. This is similar to `dmask`; the group will only have read access to files.
   - You should substitute `#AnyOtherOptions#` with whatever other options you have. For example, you might have `auto` which automatically mounts the partition on startup.
6. Once the above is done, do `sudo mount -a` to apply the changes we did to the `fstab` file. Hopefully, you shouldn't get any errors.

   You should now test that the users can access the partition. If yes, move on the the next step to add that `A` link to their Documents folder.
7. Assuming that the home directory for our `notadmin` account is `/home/notadmin`, and that this `A` folder is at `/media/123/some/folder/A`, do the following:

   ```
   ln -s /media/123/some/folder/A /home/notadmin/Documents/A
   ```

   You should now see a link under `notadmin`'s Documents, pointing to `A`. He will only have read access to it (and its subdirectories, since he has read-only access to the whole partition). Follow the same thing for other users.

All of the above should meet your requirements, except for the point I mentioned at the beginning: what kind of access should the user have to the rest of the partition? The above will give them read-only access to the whole partition, and not just the `A` partition; we're not able to set permissions to specific files/folders when mounting Windows partitions.

Comment: nothing much to say, you covered everything!

Answer (score 1):

Simply **possible with overlayfs**

Guide to mount a Windows folder in readonly mode for normal user (write mode for root or another user)

1. Create a mount point for ROOT user

   ```
   sudo mkdir /root/win
   ```
2. Create a mount point for normal user

   ```
   mkdir /home/$USER/folder
   mkdir /tmp/folder
   ```
3. Mount Windows partion in write mode

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/disk/by-label/winOS /root/win
   ```
4. Mount Windows partion's folder in readonly mode

   ```
   sudo mount -t overlayfs -o ro,lowerdir=/root/win/folder,upperdir=/tmp/folder  overlayfs /home/$USER/folder
   ```

Access writable windows partition as root user

```
sudo nautilus /root/win
```

Access readonly windows partition's folder

```
nautilus /home/$USER/folder
```

Comment: Is it O.K @bob.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount a *writable* directory in readonly mode on another location, can use **bind mount**.

For example mount *home* directory in readonly mode @ */tmp/home*

```
sudo mount --bind ~ /tmp/home
sudo mount -o ro,remount  /tmp/home
```

If you want readonly access ot a specific folder for normal user then mount the partition in an unreachable location (Example */root/abc*).